# select count(*) showing nothing (not null value, just nothing)

Tags: sql-server, count, no-data

When I run the following query I get nothing.  Not a null value but nothing[image: the image is not cutoff right after (no column name) there is nothing there] (the image is not cutoff right after (no column name) there is nothing there).

If I get rid of the last AND clause I do get a number (even if that number is zero) and if I run the query inside the NOT IN parentheses I get the expected results.  If I substitute the query inside the the NOT IN parentheses with the results I get from that query, it will give me the correct number.

I want it to say 0 instead of nothing.  COALESCE and ISNULL do not work because there is no null value returned, seems like nothing is returned.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM groups g  
    INNER JOIN item_group ig ON g.groupid = ig.groupid  
    INNER JOIN item_materiel im ON ig.itemid = im.item_id  
WHERE g.groupid = 4933  
     AND im.ItemMateriel_ID NOT IN (  
                         SELECT oim.ItemMaterielID  
                         FROM groups g  
                         INNER JOIN item_group ig ON g.groupid = ig.groupid  
                         INNER JOIN orderitem oi ON ig.itemid = oi.itemid  
                         INNER JOIN OrderItemMateriel oim ON oi.OrderItemID 
                                      = oim.OrderItemID  
                         WHERE g.groupid = 4933  
                                    )  
GROUP BY g.groupid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `GROUP BY g.groupid`. Since you are only selecting one groupid, it makes no sense to group over it anyway.